# Link background is line per line instead of a solid background, fix?

Tags: html, css

Like the title says I can't get the background of the a element to be one solid color. Instead my code make each line the color. I have even tried wrapping the php element in a new div and setting that background color but it does the same thing. Any advice is useful.

Site: http://www.whatsatyourcore.com, bottom widget titles

The html: 
`<a class="teaser-title-top" title="Social customer service and your marketing strategy" href="http://whatsatyourcore.com/?p=78"> Social customer service and your marketing strategy</a>`

CSS:

```
.teaser-title-top { background: black;} 


a.teaser-title-top {
color: #fff;}
```

The above "code boxes" are an example. The first one is what the background is doing on my titles. The second one is what I want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap it in a `div` and set that `div`s `background-color` that should work. The element you are setting the `background-color` for needs to be a block-level element (a `div` is) you can set an element to display as a block level element with `display: block;` else it will just color the background of the inline content.

Answer (score 0):

you are styling the anchor which is only going to stlye what's in it.  Try something like:

```
<div id="title-box">
     <div class="teaser-title-top">
            <a href="http://whatsatyourcore.com/?p=78" title="Social customer service and your marketing strategy"> Social customer service and your marketing strategy</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

And then style the .teaser-title-top

Answer (score 0):

As with the other answers, you can style a wrapper element.  However if you want to style just the anchor text directly, try this...

The issue is the line-height of your text.  AS you can see, it is spaced out.  If you.  The height of the line, compared to the size of the text, is bigger.

As an example, set `#bottom a { line-height: 100%; }` (which is what teh font-size is set to) and you'll see the gap go away.  You'll also see the spacing go away.  You can "bring back" the spacing with top/bottom padding, as well as changing the line-height.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it works

```
#bottom .teaser-title-top {
      color: white;
}
```

In your css file